# CASE logic when removing NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my first post, and I attempted to do a thorough search for this issue, so please accept my apologies if it has been posted elsewhere many times, but I'm wondering if anyone has encountered the following issue when attempting to remove NULLs from their result set:

```
case Occurrence
    when NULL then '0'
    else occurrence
    end as Occurrence,
case Aggregate
    when NULL then '0'
    else Aggregate
    end as Aggregate,
```

This didn't do anything to my NULLs; however, this did the trick:

```
case 
    when occurrence is NULL then '0'
    else occurrence
    end as Occurrence,
case 
    when aggregate is NULL then '0'
    else Aggregate
    end as Aggregate
```

Does anyone have any idea why this behaves this way? I'm using SQLServer2012.

I'm also not very versed in programming and only have less than a year SQL experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the ISNULL() or COALESCE() system function for handling nulls

something like

```
SELECT ISNULL(Occurrence , 0) AS Occurrence
      ,ISNULL(Aggregate  , 0) AS Aggregate
FROM Table
```

OR

```
SELECT COALESCE(Occurrence , 0) AS Occurrence
      ,COALESCE(Aggregate  , 0) AS Aggregate
FROM Table
```

The reason it didn't work in the case statement with

```
case Occurrence
    when NULL then '0'
    else occurrence
    end as Occurrence,
```

is because it is interpreting it as

```
CASE
WHEN Occurrence = NULL THEN 0
    ELSE Occurrence 
END
```

Null is checked in sql server using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` if you use any other operator with null like = , <> or <, < it yields NULL hence the unexpected results.

### Only for SQL Server 2012 and Later

In sql server 2012 and later versions you also have the IIF function

```
SELECT IIF(Occurrence IS NULL, 0, Occurrence) AS Occurrence
      ,IFF(Aggregate IS NULL , 0, Aggregate)  AS Aggregate
FROM Table
```

Comment: Add also that COALESCE is simply syntactic sugar to CASE and in some conditions is non-deterministic while ISNULL and full CASE are.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes true but coalesce has the ability to have more than two inputs , in some cases coalesce is a better choice than isnull.

Comment: Yea more inputs and type determination based on precedence not like ISNULL on first expression. People are not aware of this and ask the same question over and over.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I think what helped me understand this the most was the following:

"Null is checked in sql server using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL if you use any other operator with null like = , <> or <, < it yields NULL hence the unexpected results."

Comment: @lad2025, my apologies if you see this asked all the time. I very much appreciate the help, though.

Comment: @RJames Really no need to apology, I just want to point out some nuance  of COALESCE because everyone advise to use it over ISNULL and is part of ANSI standard. But without reading documentation may cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

You use [simple case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> The simple CASE expression operates by comparing the first expression to the expression in each WHEN clause for equivalency. If these expressions are equivalent, the expression in the THEN clause will be returned.
>
> Allows **only an equality check**.

```
case Occurrence
    when NULL then '0'
    else occurrence
end as Occurrence,
```

Which is executed as :

```
case 
   when occurence = NULL then '0'
   else occurrence
end as Occurrence
```

Then expression `occurence = NULL` return NULL and is treated *like False*

Second your case use searched CASE with full condition and works fine:

```
case 
  when occurrence IS NULL then '0'
  else occurrence
end as Occurrence,
```

So your question is about difference **column IS NULL vs column = NULL**

Comment: Very much appreciated. The fact that I was basically saying Occurrence = NULL, and now knowing that using any other operator with NULL other than IS or IS NOT really makes me understand.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select 1 where null =null
select 1 where null is null
```

your statement looks like null equals null

```
select case when null is null then 1 else 0 end

select case null when null then 1 else 0 end
```

In your case use ISNULL this will give you the results your after

```
SELECT ISNULL(null,1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was definitely the fact that I didn't understand that only IS NULL and IS NOT NULL work for manipulating NULL.

Comment: No worries it gets everyone :)